# TYPO3 News System Extension: Tag Filter only showing detail view

Tags: filter, tags, typo3, typo3-10.x

I am running TYPO3 v10.4.21 and have the News System extension by Georg Ringer installed, together with the T3SBootstrap Extension. What I would like to achieve is having a tag filter with a clickable list of tags in the sidebar, which leads to a list view of all the news articles with said tag.

I have followed the documentation as explained here: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/UsersManual/Plugins/Index.html#tag-list

That is:

1. Added Plugin to sidebar on the detail page, displaying "Tag list"
2. Under "Additional" set "PageId for list display" to an additional page with a plugin containing "list view"
3. Created several dummy articles which have different Tags added to them

However, when clicking on a tag in the sidebar I am only shown the detail view of the first article. So far I have found no other mentions of someone experiencing a similar problem.

Am I maybe missing something? Or is this a known bug perhaps?

Comment: Just tested with TYPO3 v10.4.21 and EXT:news v8.6.0 - works like a charm... I've also played around a little, but could not reproduce this behavior. There were only two cases: 1. it worked and linked to the defined list-page; 2. there was no link at all. EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/Tag/List.html uses `settings.listPid` as link-destination. Did you set `listPid` in your TS anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I did just overlook something! In case someone else stumbles upon this in the future, since this step is not mentioned in the documentation, here is what I had missed:

In the settings for the plugin displaying the list of filtered items, I had to make sure the following Plugin Options were set to:

1. Settings > What to display: "List view (without overloading detail view)"
2. Additional > Tags: include all the tags that should be available for filtering

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @JSAirways you have to disable "Disable override demand" flag